# Delphi Firedac Oracle : Raises Exception When Locating Primary key (VARCHAR or VARCHAR2)

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

example table for oracle

```
   create table appval (
     id varchar2(4) not null primary key,
     val1 number(38,0) default 0,
     val2 number(5,2) default 0);

   insert into appval (id,val1) values ('1101', 1500000);
   insert into appval (id,val2) values ('1102', 2.5);
```

delphi (Rad Studio) example

```
type 
  TValHelper = class (TComponent)
  private
    FDataSet: TFDTable;
  protected
    procedure PrepareTable;
  public 
    constructor CreateHelper(AOwner: TComponent; var ATable: TFDTable); reintroduce;
    function GetVal1(AId: string): Currency;
    function GetVal2(AId: string): Double;
  end;

constructor CreateHelper(AOwner: TComponent; var ATable: TFDTable);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  if not Assigned(ATable) then
     Raise Exception.Create('Null Parameter passed.');

  FDataSet := ATable;
  PrepareTable;
end;

procedure TValHelper.PrepareTable;
begin
  if not FDataSet.Active then
  begin
    FDataSet.Connection := Dm.FDConnection;
    FDataSet.TableName := 'appval';
    FDataSet.Open;
  end;
end;

function TValHelper.GetVal1 (AId: string): Currency;
begin
  Result := 0; {default value if false}
  if AppVal.Locate('id', AId, 
    [loCaseInsensitive, loPartialKey]) then {<-- Exception}
    Result := AppNumVal.Fields[1].AsCurrency;
end;

function TValHelper.GetVal2 (AId: string): Double;
begin
  Result := 0; {default value if false}
  if AppVal.Locate('id', AId, 
    [loCaseInsensitive, loPartialKey]) then {<-- Exception}
    Result := AppNumVal.Fields[2].AsFloat;
end;
```

when i call GetVal1 function internal "Locate" raise exception with message

```
Exception class EFDException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][Ora]-345. 
Data too large for variable 
[:FD__LC_ID]. Max len = [4], actual len = [5] Hint: 
set the TFDParam.Size to a greater value'.
```

i try to reproduce this test with other DB(SQLite) no Exception raised like oracle do.

this was bug or someting missing in my code. can someone explain.

i do a research and try to trace this error
i land into supicious block at FireDac.Comp.Client.pas
(Delphi Tokyo 10.2)

```
{LINE 12690}
procedure TFDTable.FetchWindow
begin 
  {some code}
  {line 12769 i Set Watch at Command.CommandText.Text}
  Command.CommandText.Add(GenerateSQL);
  {Watch value : 
       'SELECT A.*, A.ROWID AS FD__ROWID'
       'FROM APPVAL A'
       'WHERE ({FN UCASE(A.ID)} LIKE {FN UCASE(:FD__LC_ID)})'
       'ORDER BY A.ID ASC'
       '{LIMIT(1)}'
     :F__LC_ID <-- is param with size 4

     until this
     everything goes fine.
  } 

  // check locate params {LINE 12785}
  else if IsPrefixed(oParam.Name, C_FD_CmdGenLocate, sField) then begin
    oParam.AssignFieldValue(FieldByName(sField), GetLocateRow.ValueS[sField]);
    // made LIKE compatible String
    if FTableParams.FLocatePartial and
       (oParam.DataType in [ftString, ftWideString, ftFixedChar, ftFixedWideChar]) then
      oParam.Value := VarToStr(oParam.Value) + '%'; {LINE 12791} 
      {
         something wrong with this oParam.Value Plus 1 char '%' 
         and i assume field has only 4 so if we increase the field size 
         manualy value will be padded with space before '%' so this will
         still produce exception (oParam.Value always greater +1).
      }
  end

end;
```

how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can call it a bug. FireDAC could for case when appending **%** char increase the limit size of the parameter. However, in your case it seems that you want to locate record by the exact term rather than partial. If that is so, simply exclude the [**loPartialKey**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TLocateOptions) flag from your [**Locate**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Locate) method call. If not, you can trim the search term by one char by yourself as a quick dirty workaround.

Comment: yup, very dirty to change base firedac. at me remove loPartialKey can be worst with other code at my development. increase my code and work at my case we change from DB2 to Oracle. thx.

Comment: Well, decision is upon you. But take it as is. If you have 4 chars long field values and search by 4 chars long term, it cannot be partial, but exact. Partial search would be for terms shorter than 4 chars.

Comment: By Nature Firedac use secodary table to locate and before it's create secondary table(temp) they check for fetch status if all fetched then locate goes to memory mecanism but somehow my at case it goes directly to DBMS for try to find in remote first. so when it accessed directly length of string can cause problem because they put '%' in param as value UCASE(<-- for loCaseInsensitive)(:FD__LC_ID%(<--lopartial key)) max length for loPartialKey must -1, bytheway i realy apreciated with your suggestion.

Comment: There could be `if Length(oParam.Value) = oParam.Size then oParam.Size := oParam.Size + 1` which would increase the size of the parameter when performing search of a term in length of maximum field size, but again, if you're searching for term that is as long as the field maximum length, it's not a partial but exact search.

Comment: yup you right abut checking value for oParam but I concern about why EMBT put sql statement like '%' in value of oParam not at GenerateSql function as fullfiled sql statement, when they put '%' as value when we user pass % to Locate it's automaticly trigger PartialKey (my assumption) even worst injection or something about security concern. at firedac theway they put sql and '%' can cause lot of problem for further or for data with exceeds the Size.

Comment: You are right, the `%` char could have been appended in `GenerateSelectTable` method (I'm having older version of FireDAC, so maybe you have different method names but I can see the similar code as you've posted). It's not injectable though, because the command still uses parameters. About the SQL command, for partial locate would be better to check if the parameter value is in the length of the column size and if so, use `=` instead of `LIKE` (it will be more efficient for DBMS). And before all this starts, there might be a check for case of search term is longer than the field size.

Comment: Is glad to hear safe, my example table SQLite for comparison i pass non exact value <-- Headace for 3 hours, as my assumption when we fullfiled to max or not at loPartialKey will return a part of string so Ithink EMBT don't wants' we life with better morning tomorow.